# Celery asyncResult.ready() always returning false on AWS

Tags: django, redis, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I have used celery for my Django application computation intensive tasks. I am using Redis as a broker, and as Celery backend result.
Everything works fine on localhost. But on Aws, AsyncResult.ready() always returns false. Seems like it does not maintain state of the task.

I have AWS Elasticache redis clusters, for Redis. And elasticbeanstalk for my Django app. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    ares = AsyncResult(task_id)
    if(ares.ready()):
       return HttpResponse(ares.get())
    else:
       return HttpResponse(status=202)
```

This 'ares.ready()' always returns false on AWS, but works fine on localhost, with local redis-server

Here is my celery Configuration in settings.py:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://interacta001.a4zxsx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://interacta-001.a4zxsx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("ebdjango.tasks", )
```

Note: The redis-server on clusters is working fine, and when ping from AMI (Amazon machine) using SSH, it responds quickly. Also I am using djcelery in installed apps.

Comment: Have you checked if your redis received the message from celery ?

Comment: Figured out the problem, celery daemon worker were not started, manully started the worker using ssh, and it worked.
Can u tell me how to start celery daemon service